# is there way to make a foreign key in django readonly and still submit the form without any error?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, automation, web-applications

I have been trying to make a foreign key from my django forms read only , I am creating a web-app with system control, i don't want certain users to edit a submitted field

```
class ApproveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApproveForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Filter the queryset for the 'category' field to only include active categories
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(status='active')

        # Filter the queryset for the 'category' field to only include active categories
        self.fields['location'].queryset = Location.objects.filter(status='active')

        self.fields['location'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True    



    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('item','category','location','quantity','comments' )

        widgets = {
            'item':forms.Select(attrs={
                'class':'form-control', 
            }),
            'category':forms.Select(attrs={
                'class':'form-control',
            }),
             'location':forms.Select(attrs={
                'class':'form-control',
            }),
            'quantity':forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'class':'form-control', 'min':'0', 'readonly':'readonly'
            }),
            'comments': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'rows':4,'cols':5, 'class':'form-control'
            })

        }
```

it's not working , I have tried using hidden, it hides all the whole values leaving the label on display

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the value of existing object to user in readonly mode, you can remove the field from form and directly access via form instance like this.

1. Remove field from form

   fields = ('item','category','quantity','comments' )
2. Access field value in html via instance.

   {{form.instance.location}}